# No RFC authorization for function module RFC PING from VBA?

Tags: vba, saprfc

Good morning, everybody!

I've been looking for the solution in the last days but I really have not managed to succeed: I am trying to make a VBA code to:

1. log into SAP,
2. run some transactions,
3. export to excel.

But even the "log into SAP" part is not OK!

I tried several codes, the one below OPENS the SAP logon screen, but does not fill in any fields.

In the first attempt, I Used `CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")`:

```
Sub Entrar_SAP()

If Not IsObject(SAPguiApp) Then
    Set SAPguiApp = CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
    Set Connection = SAPguiApp.OpenConnection("xxxxxxx)", True)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
    Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "100"     
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = "user"     
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = "pass" 
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").Text = "PT" 
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").SetFocus     
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").caretPosition = 2 
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

In the second attempt, I tried `CreateObject("SAP.Functions")`, it showed:

> "RFC error received. No RFC authorization for function module RFC PING"

The code is:

```
'Declaration
Dim objBAPIControl As Object 'Function Control (Collective object)
Dim sapConnection As Object 'Connection object
Set objBAPIControl = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
Set sapConnection = objBAPIControl.Connection
sapConnection.Client = "xxxxx" 
sapConnection.User = "xxxxxx"
sapConnection.Language = "PT" 
sapConnection.hostname = "xxxxx"
sapConnection.Password = "xxxxxxxx" 'Fake password         
sapConnection.SystemNumber = "4"
sapConnection.System = "xxxxxx)"
sapConnection.Logon 
If sapConnection.Logon(1, True) <> True Then
    MsgBox "No connection to R/3!"
Exit Sub 'End program 
End If
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, RFC is a perfectly fine method for interacting with SAP. It's not out of support.

Second, you don't have enough authorization so your code will not work even if you get the syntax right. *"RFC error received. No RFC authorization for function module RFC PING".* Ask your SAP team to give you access to execute RFCs remotely. Ask for **SAP_S_RFCACL**.

On a side note, your main object of running some transactions and exporting to Excel is quite easy to do in SAP. Maybe you should just ask your SAP team to do it for you instead of developing it in VBA?

Comment: Thanks for answering, Mikael! The point is: if i do it with SAP team, there will be a high cost. So I wanna do it by myself, in a free solution!

Comment: Is there a way to do it in VBA? Thanks again!

Comment: You need authorization before you can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your pulling via an RFC read Table. This Connection will work fine for those.

```
Dim LogonControl As Object
Dim conn As Object
Dim retcd As Boolean

Set LogonControl = CreateObject("SAP.LogonControl.1")
   Set conn = LogonControl.NewConnection
conn.System = "strSystemName"
conn.Client = "100"
conn.Language = "EN"
conn.User = "sUserName"
conn.Password = "strPassword"
retcd = conn.Logon(0, True) 'True = No logon GUI 'False = logon GUI

If retcd <> True Then
    MsgBox "Login failed for- " & strSystemName & " -UserName or Password are incorrect, check them and run try again ."
    Exit Sub
End If
 Set funcControl = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
 funcControl.Connection = conn
```

From this Point on you can make your RFC call without any issues.

**But to be truthful though,** Above is almost exactly what you have as your second example. your RFC Error your getting seems like you don't have security settings for SAP to make RFC calls to whatever table your pulling from and not a problem with your login code.

*Disclaimer*: RFC_READ_TABLE is **NOT** supported by SAP and is more of a backdoor then a day to day method for pulling data.

Edit1: To Cover the Comments and not turn this into a discussion I will try and Summarize them here.

**Firstly**

the pop-up: If you want the pop-up for the log in then you need to change this line of code

```
retcd = conn.Logon(0, True)
```

to

```
retcd = conn.Logon(0, False) 'This one DISPLAYS the pop-up
```

**Secondly**

The Permissions: RFC_Read_Table uses Very Different Security Settings then a SAP t-Code uses, The technical Difference is difficult to explain but for a rule of thumb, If you cant access the SAP Table (t-Code SE16) you most likely not be able to pull it from RFC Read Table

**Thirdly**

If your company has Multiple SAP boxes (DEV, production, test) the Systemname would be *EXACTLY* what shows up on the box selection screen of SAP under name. assuming you were getting an RFC error from your second code block then the box name you used in that code would be the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Jimmy! Do you have suggestions of anything I could do to solve these security issues? Besides using VBA a lot, my knowledge of SAP and RFC is pretty small. PS: I tried your code but it shows the msgbox as if the login was incorrect, but I know that it is not.

Comment: SAP security Access can be Very different for different Organizations, 

Can you access the table your pulling from in SAP via t-code "se16"?

If you cannot view your data that way then you need to request permission from who ever sets up your SAP access so that you can have "SAP Table Access" or something like that. 

It could be that IT at your company has disabled RFC read table from everyone as it is considered a security risk If so then have fun convincing them to let you in.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have access to that. Does it mean i will never be able to logon SAP using any kind of programming until i manage to get access? Do you know why some codes manage to open the SAP logon screen? Thanks for answering again! PS: I am using Excel to do that

Comment: short answer, No You can still log into SAP, You just won't be able to pull data via RFC read table from my understanding. 

As for opening the Log in screen in my code above the line for 'conn.login(0,TRUE/FALSE)' this is what opens the login GUI. If it is False you get the Gui if True it is a silent login

Comment: Do you have any suggestions why the code you posted is not working to log in? I did change the system("1.2 - SAP ECC 6.0 - PRD (GC)"),client ("200"), language("PT"), user and password. And the code that opened the login was not this one, it was one of the many i've tried in the last days. Unfortunately yours just showed the wrong password msg box

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! The last doubt is why its not connecting to SAP with your code even the data i inserted being correct

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass RFC controls and just go for a normal scripting that imitates a human user and manually introduces username and password. [Credit to The Script Man from the SAP forums](https://answers.sap.com/questions/9105409/logon-to-session-manager-in-sap-with-vba.html):

```
 Sub SapLogin()
'Logs onto SAP system

Dim SapGuiApp As Object
Dim oConnection As Object
Dim session As Object
Dim SAPCon As Object, SAPSesi As Object
Dim SAPGUIAuto As Object, SAPApp As Object
Dim system As String

system = "XX" 'SAP system you will log on to like "01. ENGINEERING PRODUCTION [EG1]

If SapGuiApp Is Nothing Then
    Set SapGuiApp = CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
End If
If oConnection Is Nothing Then
    Set oConnection = SapGuiApp.OpenConnection(system, True)
End If
If SAPSesi Is Nothing Then
   Set SAPSesi = oConnection.Children(0)
End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = FALSE

 With SAPSesi

    .FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "100"
    .FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = "USERNAME"
    .FindById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = "PASSWORD"
    .FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").Text = "EN"
    .FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0

    'start extraction

    .FindById("wnd[0]").Maximize
    .FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/TCODEYOUWANTTORUN"
    .FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0

    '...
    'etc
    '...

    End With

     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     MsgBox "After clicking OK, this SAP session is terminated."
End Sub
```