# Opening af file in EasyDMS with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-erp

I am starting to learn VBA, and I have learned how to open and read documents. At work, files are stored in a DMS system.

How can I open files in DMS with Excel VBA?

Comment: There's a gulf of information between opening a file in VBA and checking out and opening a file from a DMS like EasyDMS. You may need to use the `SAP.FUNCTIONS` object and hope that the ABAP function you need (like `BAPI_DOCUMENT_CHECKOUTMODIFY2`) is RFC enabled in your SAP install.

Comment: The question may be short but it's too broad for SO. Please add more details such as: 1. what type of file are you opening 2. by open do you mean copy the file to your hd 3. what resouce has you currently consulted e.g. http://www.dllbook.com/know/excel-vba-automatically-checkout-and-checkin-documents-from-sap-r-3.html

Comment: By googling I also found examples using   `BAPI_DOCUMENT_CHECKOUTMODIFY2`. For my use I don't want to check out any files. I would like, if possible, to open a DMS document (e.g. excel-document) and extract data from an excel sheet into another excel sheet.
I managed to log onto SAP from VBA with help from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983234/sap-logon-with-vba), but how do I search and open a DMS-document then?